# Datepicker jquery and knockout, bind invalid values

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, datepicker

I am using [this example of datepicker](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NAgNV/) that uses jQuery and Knockout, but the problem is that when I set a date that is invalid, the binding does not work, because it doesn't mirror the value that is in the input. (Example: try setting 00/00/0000 in the input).

The only thing that I changed was to put `$el.val()` instead of `$el.datepicker("getDate")`, because despite of defining the `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'`, the `$el.datepicker("getDate")` gives me another format.

```
<input id="data" data-bind="datepicker: myDate, datepickerOptions: { dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'} />
```

```
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function() {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    observable($el.val()); //$el.datepicker("getDate")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to allow an invalid date? And if you must allow an invalid date, what do you want the value of the bound observable to be? 
Cant you :
$el.datepicker(options).attr('readonly', 'readonly');

This will ensure that only valid dates can be entered.

Comment: I would like that if the input was incorrect, it would be on the view and in the model the same value. But I see your point and you are correct, I should probably just try to find some kind of validation, since I would like the user to be able to input values.